# How to programatically create pull request with changed file using GitHub API

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-api

How can I create PR on Github using their API? Let's imagine I have `package.json` file as a string and I want to make changes to this file. So I parse it, make changes to it and then what exactly I need to do to make it look like I made those changes locally after checking out the new branch, making changes, commiting them to new branch and the pushing them to remote? I see that they have POST API endpoint to create a commit and POST API endpoint to create a PR, but I don't see where I put the file I changed.

Answer (score 3):

Using something like [GitJS](https://github.com/steveukx/git-js) could be a solution.

This library is a simple wrapper around the git command line.

Instead of using the Github API you could just work the git commands programatically with a library like this.

That way you don't have to work with the much more complicated API and have the benefit of supporting other source control sites too.

Looking at their [example](https://github.com/steveukx/git-js#push-with--u) we can see it's incredibly easy to commit and push a file using javascript:

```
require('simple-git')()
   .add('./*')
   .commit("first commit!")
   .addRemote('origin', 'some-repo-url')
   .push(['-u', 'origin', 'master'], () => console.log('done'));
```

Make sure you refer to the [usage documentation](https://github.com/steveukx/git-js#usage) before trying that example to ensure you configure everything correctly.

Alternatively, you can use the package [Octokit](https://github.com/octokit/rest.js) to more easily interface with the Github API.

When adding, committing and pushing a file via the API you must first start by creating a tree. Then you use that tree as part of the commit request, update the references and finally push the commit.

You can find a working example on [this Github issue](https://github.com/octokit/rest.js/issues/1308).

Comment: I don't have the repository cloned and saved to my filesystem, I only have access to string representation of file content. And I must use Github API since I'm accessing the repository content via OAuth token, meaning I don't have access to them from git.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Updated my answer for you :)

Comment: The link https://github.com/octokit/rest.js/issues/1308 is a 404 page now. Could you please fix it? Thanks.